# Android: What is the different between textview onclick and button on click?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a doubt between the views TextView and Button. I know the basic function of TextView and Button but still need to be clear about onClickListener functionality. Both views having the setOnclickListener function. How the compiler takes this when TextView and Button onClick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a doubt between the containers TextView and Button

They are not "containers", as they cannot contain other widgets. `TextView` and `Button` are widgets.

> How the compiler takes this when TextView and Button onClick?

`TextView` is a Java class. `Button` is a Java class. `Button` inherits from `TextView`. `TextView` has an `setOnClickListener()` method. That method is available on all subclasses of `TextView`, including `Button`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference, a `Button` is a `TextView`

Comment: Imageview onClick and ImageButton onClick also same?

Answer (score 2):

Both the `TextView` and `Button` are the same when using an `onClickListener`